# How to build and publish asp.net core based server-side and angular based client-side project?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I developed a project using asp.net core 5 and angular 15 technologies for backend and frontend respectively. asp.net core MVC part of project is created in a separate folder named **serverApi**, and the angular part of project is generated in another folder named **clientSpa**.
pakcage.json of SPA part is:

```js
{
  "name": "client-spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.11",
    "jalali-ts": "^2.0.5",
    "material-icons": "^1.13.1",
    "ng-persian-datepicker": "^6.1.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-print": "^1.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

and serverApi.csproj :

```js
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.17" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="5.0.17" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="5.0.17" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.17">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="5.0.17" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.17" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.17">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Resources\Images" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It should be noted that when I created serverApi project using visual Studio, I added the Existing Website (clientSpa) so that contents of the Angular project will be seen whenever I open the Solution of the project. However, both parts of the project are in separate folders. Given the above description, how can I build the project to publish on a server with IP: X.Y.Z.W? Thank you very much for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.
I tried to imitate with the Angular-api template in visual studio.
[image]

I create an api fisrt then add an existing angular website.
To make them build together you need modify 3 files :
serverApi.csproj
launchsettings.json
 angular.json (clientSpa project)
For Serverapi.csproj and launchsettings.json, You can copy whole from the template.
For angular.json, you can also copy from template, but need replace the template project name to yours.
The key file to make api working is proxy.conf.js ,you should need to make it work with your own api
[image]

I tested above that make 2 separate project build together and deploy together to IIS.

Copy your project to a template may also be a solution.